# BoxLayout 'cols' doens't work in AnchorLayout

Tags: python, kivy

Here is my kivyfile.kv

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:
   
<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "left" 
        anchor_y: "top"       
        BoxLayout:  
            cols:2            
            orientation: 'vertical'            
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.minimum_size
            Button:
                text: "Button 1"
                size_hint: (None,None)
                width:200
                height:30
            Button: 
                text: "Button2"
                size_hint: (None,None)
                width:200
                height:30
            TextInput:
                id: url      
                multiline: False
                size_hint: (None,None)
                width:200
                height:30
            TextInput:
                id: url2      
                multiline: False
                size_hint: (None,None)
                width:200
                height:30
```

Here is my .py file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen





class FirstWindow(Screen):
    pass
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv=Builder.load_file('kivyfile.kv')

class Downloader(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Downloader().run()
```

What I am trying to achive, is to get a BoxLayout at the top left corner, which has two columns - Button and TextInput NEXT TO it. However, it only does all components one under each other. I have also a future question on how to add another BoxLayout NEXT TO the previous BoxLayout that I have. As in - how to make it be on the right side of existing BoxLayout, how to position it.

Comment: The class `BoxLayout` has no attribute `cols`. Did you mean `GridLayout` ?

Comment: Yes, it fixed my problem. Thanks a lot.